# what's the meaning of CloseWith of flink

Tags: apache-flink

My code is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zQjJ8NfPjQ/)

could anyone tell me what' the meaning of`CloseWith` in above code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The implementation says this: "This method defines the end of the iterative program part that will be fed back to the start of the iteration."

Comment: You should be aware that the use of Iterations with the DataStream API is strongly discouraged, since this feature is incompatible with checkpointing.

Comment: Got it ,Many Thanks for your help!